# Buzz in electric guitar recording

Tags: guitar, recording, buzz

I use some sort of synthesizer or something that has a plug in,plug out,line in, line out. I plug my guitar into it and then into an amp so I can hear it, then I use a 3.5mm aux cord to plug into my computer. I use audacity to record because I couldn't figure out the daw or whatever virtual recording studio things. When I record the guitsr has a low buzzing sound on it throughout the whole track. Through noise cancellation I can cut it out a little but it still sounds wierd. How can I record a better sound?

Additionally, if I purchased this

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000J5UEGQ/ref=mp_s_a_1_21?qid=1446091936&sr=8-21&pi=AC_SX110_SY165_QL70&keywords=audio+interface&dpPl=1&dpID=61zyGSCoRnL&ref=plSrch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J5UEGQ)

Would I be able to record my guitar and a microphone at the same time and plug it into my computer using an aux cord?

Comment: Seriously? It's highly unlikely you'll get half decent results when you plug a guitar into “some sort of synthesizer or something”. Get a ruddy simple audio interface with high-Z instrument input. They're available from as little as 20 € nowadays.

Comment: My friend gave it to me because he wasn't using it. It's a digitech rp200

Comment: The noise is probably coming from the aux chord which is probably unshielded, and if you have it connected to the mic-in jack and have the computer mic input set up with +gain, it will be worse. At the least you should be connected via line-in not mic. Computers generate a lot of noise and an unshielded aux cable is likely going to act as an antenna. You might pick up HD noise especially

Comment: Duuuuude just get a super cheap usb audio interface. Your noise could be coming from your digitech, the guitar itself, noisy power outlet, unshielded cables, etc. Too many bad variables in your setup right now. Eliminate the main culprit: the digitech. Use computer or phone plugins with some sort of amplitube or guitar rig setup. Something like the link below should work just fine. http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/UCG102/p/P0198

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is no... The device you linked to is a Behringer **mixer**. It is not designed to record audio to your computer. Although you could do it in theory, it's not the right way to record. Like some other folks have suggested, your best bet would be to invest in a low-cost audio interface with a high impedance input for your guitar. Also, since you want to record vocals and guitar simultaneously you're going to want to get yourself a two-channel interface. Lastly, make sure you get an interface with phantom power should you ever decide to record using a condenser mic. Read more on phantom power [here](http://www.dawsons.co.uk/blog/what-is-phantom-power).

This [Behringer interface](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/behringer-u-phoria-um2) might actually do the trick. At 30 bucks, you're not going to get a super high-quality piece of gear, but for someone just getting into recording, $30 is a pretty small investment.

Hope that helps. Good luck!